# Binding model to a grid and posting back selection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm attempting to bind a model to a grid and get back selections. I'm able to pass the model in and display the data I expect along with checkboxes for the selection. However when I try to pass the model back to the controller I just seem to get back the same model initially passed into the view without any selection changes.

View:

```
@model ExViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Classes)
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(c => c.IsChecked).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= IsChecked ? checked='checked':'' # class='chkbx' />" + "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='#= IsChecked#' />").Width(50);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Width(175);
    columns.Bound(c => c.Details).Width(175);
})
.Scrollable().Groupable().Sortable().Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
           )
)

@using (Html.BeginForm("CallNext", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input hidden="hidden" id="model_output" name="model_output" value="@(Json.Encode(Model))" />
    <input id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next >" />
}

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#grid').on('click', '.chkbx', function () {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            var grid = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid;
            var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
            dataItem.set('IsChecked', checked);
        })
    })
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CallNext(string model_output)
{ 
 . . . 
}
```

Using the above, the model_output I get back in the controller has all the default values for the IsChecked flag for Classes. I'm not sure what I'm overlooking - I've looked though a few examples online but I'm afraid I don't have much experience with Kendo, so I'm unsure as to what's going wrong. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This `Json.Encode(Model)` is constant after razor page is rendered into html. That mean if you click on checkbox  this `Model` object will still be the same. Do you need custom checkboxes, because Kendo UI offer row selection out of the box?

Comment: Unfortunately the checkboxes are required, are there any other methods of passing data? Could I update if I passed the model in a viewbag for example?

Comment: can you confirm that the click handler is running ? I would presume yes.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the click handler is running ? I would presume yes.

The form posts the original model because the `value="@(Json.Encode(Model))"` is constructed at page render time not at page view runtime.

Try changing the submit button to perform a grid `saveChanges`

```
$('#grid').data("kendoGrid").saveChanges().
```

saveChanges calls the data source sync.

You could also use tool bars, they do even more of the plumbing for you.  See the [demos](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing) for more info.